# Axios returns https status 401 but same curl example succeeds

Tags: node.js, api, request, axios

I'm sending a `post` request to the api of YooKassa to create a payment. My request works fine with `curl` in the terminal, and in Postman. But similar request doesn't work in nodejs when using `axios`. Both examples below:

Node.js:

```
/**
         * Generate idempotence key if not present
         * @see https://yookassa.ru/developers/using-api/basics#idempotence
         */
        if (!idempotenceKey) idempotenceKey = uuid()

        const uri = 'https://api.yookassa.ru/v3/payments'

        const payload = {
            amount: {
                value: '2.50',
                currency: 'RUB',
            },
            confirmation: { type: 'embedded' },
            capture: true,
            receipt: {
                customer: {
                    email: 'test12@test.ru',
                },
                items: [
                    {
                        description: 'Album',
                        quantity: '1.00',
                        amount: { value: '2.00', currency: 'RUB' },
                        vat_code: '1',
                    },
                ],
            },
            save_payment_method: false,
            description: 'Order №72',
        }

        try {
            const { data } = await axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: uri,
                data: payload,
                auth: {
                    user: this.shopId,
                    pass: this.secretKey,
                },
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Idempotence-Key': idempotenceKey,
                },
            })

            return data
        } catch (error) {
            return `Error: ${error}`
        }
```

Error:

```
"Error: Error: Request failed with status code 401"
```

`Curl` request works:

```
curl https://api.yookassa.ru/v3/payments \
  -X POST \
  -u user:pass \
  -H 'Idempotence-Key: <Random uuid>' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
                "amount": {"value": "2.00", "currency": "RUB"},
                "confirmation": {"type": "embedded"},
                "capture": true,
                "description": "Order №72",
                "receipt": {
                        "customer": {
                                "email": "test12@test.ru"
                        },
                        "items": [
                                {
                                        "description": "Album",
                                        "quantity": "1.00",
                                        "amount": {"value": "2.00","currency": "RUB"},
                                        "vat_code": "1"
                                }
                        ]
                },
                "save_payment_method": false
        }'
```

Or suggest me how to debug the 401 error.

Username and password were omitted from the question.

Thanks!

Comment: Try checking the error response headers, those might contain `WWW-Authenticate`. To inspect the error you could use [`util.inspect`](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/how-to-use-util-inspect/) instead of just ``Error: ${error}``

Comment: @Aivaras Ok, how to convert normal view? after use return util.inspect(error), I get unreadable debug

Comment: `util.inspect` returns a `string`. It is not clear if code can handle this. The other way to see that string is to use debugging and add a breakpoint or just `console.log`

Comment: Status code 401 is an authorization failure. Are you sure shopId and secretKey are correct?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the error. I wrote incorrect keys for authorization (**user** and **pass**). Axios needs a different key name: **username** and **password**.